# How can I set the version of BeautifulSoup4 from 4.6.0 to 4.8.0?

Tags: terminal, beautifulsoup

I want to upgrade the version of beautifulsoup4 from 4.6.0 to 4.8.0 and I have installed the 4.8.0 successfully. However, the output is 4.6.0 if I use `print(bs4.version)` to test it. According to the terminal, it says

> Found existing installation: beautifulsoup4 4.6.0 Not uninstalling beautifulsoup4 at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6, as it is in the standard library. Can't uninstall 'beautifulsoup4'. No files were found to uninstall. Successfully installed beautifulsoup4-4.8.0

I have tried to use `$ pip uninstall BeautifulSoup4==4.6.0`, but the notification is still the same:

> Not uninstalling beautifulsoup4 at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6, as it is in the standard library. Can't uninstall 'beautifulsoup4'. No files were found to uninstall.

I want to run my program with 4.8.0 as default because I cannot use certain function otherwise...

Comment: I have also tried `pip install bs4 -U` but nothing was changed